# Demonstration of a theorem

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I've this Theorem:
$f:X\rightarrow[0,M],$ f null out of E,f measurable $[0,M] \subset E$ then $\exists \left \{ \phi_n\right \}_n,\left \{\psi_n\right \}_n $ two sequences of simple functions:
$$1) \phi_n<=f<= \psi_n \forall n\in  \mathbb{N}$$
$$2) \psi_n-\phi_n<= \frac{M}{n}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$$3) \int_X \phi_n d\mu<=\int_X f d\mu<=\int_X \psi_n d\mu<=\int_X \phi_n d\mu+\frac{\mu(E)M}{n}$$
and this demostration:
$$[0,M]=(0,\frac{M}{n}] \cup (\frac{M}{n},\frac{2M}{n}] \cup ... \cup (\frac{(n+1)M}{n},\frac{nM}{n}]$$
$$E_n:=f^{-1}((\frac{(n+1)M}{n},\frac{nM}{n}])  \subseteq  E$$
$$\phi_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(j-1)M}{n}\chi_{E_j} \space \space\psi_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(jM}{n}\chi_{E_j}\Rightarrow \int_X\psi_n-\phi_n=\frac{M}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \mu(E_j)<=\frac{M}{n}\mu(E) $$
$$\int_X f^+d\mu+\int_Xf^-d\mu?\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty  \Leftrightarrow  summable \Leftrightarrow f\in L^1\mu(x)$$

those are the clipboard of my friend but I can't completely understand the demonstration and I can't tell what point (1 ,2 or 3) he demonstrated. Can you tell me what he has done and a simple and more elegant demonstration?

Comment: Probably $f^{-1}([0,M])\subset E \dots$ instead.

Comment: Yes this is what I was thinking.I have not changed it because I wanted to recopy the clipboard without changing anything.